# Storing in request scope - from SOAPHandler through to @Producer

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, jax-ws, cdi

I need to dynamically assign EntityManagers to my beans at runtime based on the contents of a soap header. My plan is to extract the info from the header with a SOAPHandler and then store it in the request scope. I have a method @Producer that I envisage accessing this request scope, examining the stored variable, and returning the appropriate entitymanager.

(The EntityManagers refer to different DB's with the same structure, but different data).

**MY PROBLEM IS THIS**: How do I access the request context to store the name (on the SOAPHandler side) and then, again, retrieve the request context to retrieve the name?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question:

Stick it in the SOAPMessageContext, as follows:

> context.put("VARIABLE_KEY", whateverIWantObject );
>
> context.setScope("VARIABLE_KEY", Scope.APPLICATION);

(The Scope.APPLICATION is important).

In the service layer you can then get the message context from the web service context, which you can inject in; the message context will then have your object:

> @Resource WebServiceContext webContext;
>
> ObjectType theObject =
>   (ObjectType) webContext.getMessageContext().get("VARIABLE_KEY");